# RSTP 802.1w maximum network loop diameter

Tags: loop, ieee-802.1w

Can anybody direct me to a calculation of the maximum network diameter (number of devices) on an RSTP tree (RSTP, NOT STP)? 
As far as I can understand from the standard and the RFC, there is no such a limit as RSTP does not use timers. What is the maximum loop you have configured ?

Most (if not all) industrial switches all have proprietary protocols which improve convergence time, and most require physical port directionality configuration but I'm interested in plain RSTP.

Comment: I deleted your opinion-based question.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no theoretical limit, but memory/CPU may impose practical limits on particular hardware.  Depending on the topology, increasing the number of devices increases the convergence time.  When that becomes a problem depends on your particular situation.

In my experience, loops tend to be small.  I don't recall ever seeing a looped configuration larger than 3 or 4 devices.